# Determine driver from file

Tags: windows-10, drivers, device-manager

How can I determine the driver from a file it has installed?

I am getting system crashes and analyzing the dump file with windbg points to

```
\SystemRoot\System32\drivers\HDAudBus.sys
```

I know it's an audio driver, but I don't know exactly which driver it's from in order to troubleshoot further.

Device Manager tracks the driver files, but doesn't have a "search by file" feature that I see.

Comment: It's a Microsoft driver. The solution you should be looking for depends on the exact error so I suggest you ask about that specifically, after searching for yourself, if course.

Comment: Thanks, I found it in Device Manager (twice) under System Devices>>High Definition Audio Controller, which is up to date and has nothing to roll back to. The error is Bug Check 0x9F: DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE. Still investigating.

Comment: The crash probably has nothing to do with your audio driver.  It is probably a problem with your power management sub-system. It looks like ***something*** is pulling the plug going to the audio hardware.  Question is.. is it software or hardware? if it is software, play with your power management configuration.. try disabling as much as you can.  If the problem goes away, bring things back one at a time until it breaks again.  If it's hardware.. good luck.  I got nothing...